# PostgreSQL 9.3: Split one column into multiple

Tags: postgresql, split, postgresql-9.3

I want to split one column that is `colb` in the given below example into two columns
like `column1` and `column2`.

I have a table with two columns:

**Example**:

```
create table t3
(
    cola varchar,
    colb varchar
);
```

Insertion:

```
insert into t3 values('D1','2021to123'),
                     ('D2','112to24201'),
                     ('D3','51to201');
```

I want to split the `colb` values into two columns like the following expected result:

**Expected Result**:

```
cola      column1        column2
---------------------------------
D1        2021           123
D2        112            24201
D3        51             201
```

Comment: but `t3` have only two columns right ??

Comment: Need some more clarification,you want to get 3 columns in selct or creating additional 2 column before insert into t3 ?

Comment: @unique_id, Yes! It is. I want 3 columns in the `select` statement.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
select cola
      ,split_part(colb, 'to', 1) col1
      ,split_part(colb, 'to', 2) col2 
from t3
```

Quoted from the PostgreSQL Documentation:

> split_part(string text, delimiter text, field int)
>
> Split string on delimiter and return the given field (counting from
> one)