# Split column into columns using split_part returning empty

Tags: postgresql, split

I have a column stored as `text` in postgres 9.6. It's an address and some of the rows have format like `BUILD NAME, 40`

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584967/split-comma-separated-column-data-into-additional-columns) answer which looks like what i want, if i run;

```
select split_part('BUILD NAME, 40', ',', 2) as address_bldgno
```

It returns; `40` as I want.

When i try;

```
select 
split_part(address, ', ', 1) as address_bldgname,
split_part(address, ', ', 2) as address_bldgno
from table;
```

It runs but returns empty values

Comment: Related later answer with detailed explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45770999/939860

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned:

> ...some of the rows have format...

I suspect anything that doesn't contain comma returns empty values.
That is due to the `split_part` condition does not find a match for the argument.

To illustrate how different **address** values are split here's some example:

```
WITH    "table" ( address ) AS (
            VALUES
                ( 'BUILD NAME, 40' ),   -- first and second have value
                ( 'BUILD NAME' ),       -- only first have value (bldgname)
                ( '40' ),               -- only first have value (bldgname)
                ( ', 40' ),             -- first is empty string, second is value
                ( 'BUILD NAME,' ),      -- first is value, second is empty string
                ( NULL ),               -- both are NULL
                ( '' )                  -- no match found, both are empty strings
        )
SELECT  split_part( address, ', ', 1 ) as address_bldgname,
        split_part( address, ', ', 2 ) as address_bldgno
FROM    "table";


-- This is how it looks in result:
 address_bldgname | address_bldgno
------------------+----------------
 BUILD NAME       | 40
 BUILD NAME       |
 40               |
                  | 40
 BUILD NAME,      |
                  |
                  |
(7 rows)
```

If you want to set some defaults for NULL and empty string I recommend to read also: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23767625/6723862)

Comment: I don't understand what is happening here, in your example your results are what i want. If i insert my column and table names i get no results.

Comment: Sure you are not adding any other conditions in your query? Maybe share exact table description and exact query with execution plan as I think issue then you have is somewhere else than in `split_part` function.

Answer (score 0):

Answer found here; 
[PostgreSQL 9.3: Split one column into multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29002141/postgresql-9-3-split-one-column-into-multiple)

Should have been;

```
select somecol 
,split_part(address, ', ', 1) as address_bldgname
,split_part(address, ', ', 2) as address_bldgno
from table;
```

By adding another column to the select I get all the values of that column back, and the split_part() results where they exist.

Comment: Sorry to say, but this really doesn't answer the question raised. The solution provided in your answer is exactly the same thing already said in the question that was tried. You just repeated that with different syntax :)

Comment: It worked for me by selecting another column `somecol` the results are as i would expect ie i get a name split from a number, added explanation in my answer to this affect